# Bigquery matching words counts between two tables

Tags: google-bigquery

given these two tables (`documents` and `labels`) how can I find match counts for all the label's `pattern`s from the `labels` table,  found in the `document` field of `documents` table (count exact matches, using regex is optional)

```
WITH documents  AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, "foo bar, foo baz" AS document UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, "foo bar bar qux" UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, "etc blah blah"
),

labels as (
  select 'FOO_LABEL' as label, 'foo' as pattern UNION ALL
  select 'FOO_LABEL', 'qux' UNION ALL
  select 'BAR_LABEL', 'bar' UNION ALL
  select 'ETC_LABEL', 'etc'
)
```

the expected matches counts by document:

```
id, label, cnt
1,  FOO_LABEL, 2
1,  BAR_LABEL, 1
2,  FOO_LABEL, 2
2,  BAR_LABEL, 2
3,  ETC_LABEL, 1
```

the difference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70910795/create-a-array-of-key-value-structs-from-regex-matches) question is that I need actual match counts

and unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644990/bigquery-dataprep-efficient-way-to-extract-word-counts-to-convert-html-to-pl) question my patterns are coming from a separate table

there are ~100M documents, and ~1000 rows in labels table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, label, count(*) cnt
from documents, unnest(regexp_extract_all(document, r'[\w]+')) pattern
join labels
using(pattern)
group by id, label
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: just realized i actually needed substring match vs. word match, slightly modified your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73522957/165130 , thanks again

Answer (score 0):

[Mikhail Berlyant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221944/mikhail-berlyant)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73520693/165130) above is perfect, I just realized I needed substring match instead of exact word match, so i slightly modified it by replacing `using(pattern)` with `ON STRPOS(word, pattern)>0` in the `JOIN`:

```
WITH documents  AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, "foo bar foobar qux" AS document UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, "foooooo barbar"
),

labels as (
  select 'FOO_LABEL' as label, 'foo' as pattern UNION ALL
  select 'FOO_LABEL', 'qux' UNION ALL
  select 'BAR_LABEL', 'bar' 
)

select id, label, count(*) cnt
from documents, unnest(regexp_extract_all(document, r'[\w]+')) word
join labels
ON STRPOS(word, pattern)>0 --faster that regexp_contains(word, pattern)
group by id, label
```

[image]

**Edit**: another minor change to work with phrases/sentences instead of matching individual words (the doc is split into phrases delimited by commas, etc), so that it works for *multi-word patterns*.
this misses some counts (i.e. repeated substring matches within phrase) but faster overall

```
WITH documents  AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, "foo 123 test foo 123" AS document UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, "all bars, all bars all bars "
),

labels as (
  select 'FOO_LABEL' as label, 'foo 123' as pattern UNION ALL
  select 'BAR_LABEL', 'all bar' 
)

select id, label, count(*) cnt
from documents, UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(document , r'([^.!;(),\n~|]+)')) AS phrase
join labels
ON STRPOS(phrase, pattern)>0 
group by id, label
```

[image]